# Generate and Verify Voucher Code Using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on generating voucher code.
Current case is:

- Voucher is ranging from 0-999, and generated once a week with an unique code for each voucher.
- Can be verified later to check validity.
- There's a secret key for each week, I used the random generated secret key to encrypt the voucher number to code.
- I've found out that the code is guessable, for example:

  '002' => '\xec\xbe\x98'

  '003' => '\xec\xbe\x99'
- then I tried to use MD5 to hash the code but it's too long(32 digit), and can be time consuming as I wrap the code in a qrcode for the voucher that I generate.

currently I'm using pycrypto module with CFB mode AES encryption,

can anyone tell me which is a preferred method to generate a verifiable voucher code ?

Comment: this is opinion based and as such seems an ill fit for stack overflow

Comment: @MattCoubrough But I've seen a lot of opinion based question here, and I don't see that as a problems, but sorry if it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Hashids](http://hashids.org/python/) module is probably what you're after:

```py
from hashids import Hashids
hash_id = Hashids(salt='your_secret_here', min_length=8)
hash_id.encrypt(0)   # aDnwJKQZ
hash_id.encrypt(999) # p32jAqVW

# it is reversible
hash_id.decrypt('p32jAqVW')  # (999,)
```

It has some good features for voucher code generation such as curse word filtering and configurable alphabet.

It is not a hardened encryption solution but for voucher codes with limited value I'm sure it would provide enough protection from brute-force attack, especially if you change the secret each week.

Comment: this is what I'm after,  thanks alot, will try it out